# Calculating the hash of any substring in logarithmic time

Tags: algorithm, hash

Question came up in relation to this article:
https://threads-iiith.quora.com/String-Hashing-for-competitive-programming

The author presents this algorithm for hashing a string:

[image]

where S is our string, Si is the character at index i, and p is a prime number we've chosen.

He then presents the problem of determining whether a substring of a given string is a palindrome and claims it can be done in logarithmic time through hashing.

He makes the point we can calculate from the beginning of our whole string to the right edge of our substring:

[image]

and observes that if we calculate the hash from the beginning to the left edge of our substring (F(L-1)), the difference between this and our hash to our right edge is basically the hash of our substring:

[image]

This is all fine, and I think I follow it so far. But he then immediately makes the claim that this allows us to calculate our hash (and thus determine if our substring is a palindrome by comparing this hash with the one generated by moving through our substring in reverse order) in logarithmic time.

I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious but how does this allow us to calculate the hash in logarithmic time?

Comment: I think its more suitable for cs.stackexchange.

Comment: Good question, but I agree. This is better suited for our sister site http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's basically the same problem as getting the sum of a subarray from the prefix-sum (that part is constant time), except you have to multiply by the modular multiplicative inverse of p^k to "move" it to the beginning (this part is log time). Edit: hey wait, that article explains this already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that you can calculate the difference in constant time. Let me restate the difference (I'll leave the modulo away for clarity):

```
diff = ∑_{i=L to R} S_i ∗ p^i
```

Note that this is not the hash of the substring because the powers of `p` are offset by a constant. Instead, this is (as stated in the article)

```
diff = Hash(S[L,R])∗p^L
```

To derive the hash of the substring, you have to multiply the difference with `p^-L`. Assuming that you already know `p^-1` (this can be done in a preprocessing step), you need to calculate `(p^-1)^L`. With the square-and-multiply method, this takes `O(log L)` operations, which is probably what the author refers to.

This may become more efficient if your queries are sorted by `L`. In this case, you could calculate `p^-L` incrementally.

Comment: Ok I see. I noticed it in the article but missed the logic of why there was the extra p^L term. So just to make it clear to anyone else who didn't completely get it: say we want to hash the string "pet". We'd apply our hash function and the p terms would be p^0, p^1 and p^2. Now say we're trying to hash the substring "pet" in "carpet". Our p terms would be p^3, p^4 and p^5. A hash function when applied to the same string should produce the same result, but here it doesn't. Factoring a p^L term out (p^3) we can see the difference is the extra p^L term as Nico mentions here in his answer.